# How to find a char pointer, in a 2-d char array in C?

Tags: c, pointers

Hi so Im fairly new to C.

Basically what I am asking is this:

So I have a 2-D `char` array, that is representing a list of strings (`char array[size][20]`).

I then have another string, which I am representing as a `char` pointed (`char *word`).

What I want my function to do, is to go through each of the strings in my array, and if it finds the word to `return 1`.

However Im quite confused about pointers, so I'm not sure how to write this. I started with just using a for loop, going through the lines of the array. And then `if(word = array[i]) return 1`. But this doesn't work for me.

I hope this made sense, if not I will try explain again. And I'll greatly appreciate any answers. I dont really need code. Just a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that your array consists of *null-terminated* strings (i.e. strings of length at most 19), then [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp) is your solution:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>

size_t find_in_array(char array[][20], size_t size, char * word)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i != size; ++i)
        if (strcmp(array[i], word) == 0)
            return i;

    return size;
}
```

This will return the offset if the word was found, and `size` otherwise.

**Usage:**

```
char array[3][20] = { "Hello", "World", "Jim" };

size_t i = find_in_array(array, 3, "Jim");  // returns "2"
```

The word was found if "i != 3".

Comment: Any special reason for returning `size` and not `(size_t)-1`?

Comment: @H2CO3: Sure. "Not found" equals "end"-iterator :-) If C++ taught us one thing, it's how to [talk about ranges](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9963438/596781).

Comment: you're a C++ guy, right? :P (Also, I'd suggest changing `3` to `sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array)`.) And don't try to teach me about that :) In Cocoa, we also have `struct NSRange { unsigned location; unsigned length; }`

Comment: Thanks so much. Worked perfectly. Will read up about strcmp now to understand it. Thanks a million :D

Answer (score 2):

Your given comparison is only comparing the value of the *pointer* itself is equal, not that the contents of the memory that the pointers are pointing at are the same (also, in your example a single equal is assignment, not comparison).

Your array really looks like this diagram I scribbled up:
[image: Array of an array of characters]

What you want to do is to use the strcmp or other such functions to compare that the memory pointed to by your word variable is equal to any of the individual strings in the array.

In languages with pointers, it helps to draw out memory like I have done here, and keep in mind that a pointer is not the actual contents of your memory but just a way to locate it.

Answer (score 1):

This is C, not C++. Using `==` will compare the strings' addresses numerically, and not their contents. To test for string equality, use the `strcmp()` function, which returns 0 if its arguments are the same string:

```
int has_word(const char *word, const char list[][20], size_t n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (strcmp(word, list[i]) == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As per your needs, this function will return 1 if it finds the 0-terminated string `word` among the first `n` elements of the `list` array of strings.

Comment: Are we sure we're not confusing arrays, pointers, arrays of pointers and pointers to arrays? And that we're compiling with *all warnings*? :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB Haven't compiled this using a compiler, only in brain :P Actually, I used `index` for the sake of verbosity, and only completed it to an entire function, but there I used the idiomatic `index`... Also, undeclared identifiers don't need `-Wall`, they throw an error immediately (if the creator of a compiler cares about his reputation...)

Comment: @KerrekSB and where did I make the pointer vs. array confusion?

Comment: Well, the array is profoundly wrong, I'm afraid. Everything else is a minor ailment. But please do try to compile this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the functions in `string.h`, specifically `strstr()`.

Wikipedia has a pretty decent page on [C String Handling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling).

Answer (score 0):

At first,`word = array[i]` is definitely not a good way to compare strings. You should use `strcmp`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/

I have just answered another question really similar to yours. Look at this question, it could give you some ideas: [Returning and printing string array index in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147515/returning-and-printing-string-array-index-in-c/13147784#13147784)